# Printing through bluetooth with HP P1109W

Tags: printer, bluetooth

I recently purchased an HP P1109W LaserJet online, and it is set to arrive next week. I was hoping to print via Bluetooth from my laptop to this printer, and I was wondering what I would need to set up this connection. My laptop is already Bluetooth enabled, what I need is some sort of Bluetooth adapter for the printer.

The reason I want to set up printing through Bluetooth is because I will be on the campus-wide network (I am a university student) and printing over WiFi sounds very troublesome if not outright disallowed.

I took a look at the HP BT500 Bluetooth Adapter for printers, but mine doesn't seem to be on the list of compatible printers. Are there any methods to achieving what I want (wireless printing in my dorm room)?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Probably goes without saying, you should have taken all this into consideration before you purchased the printer. Is there a reason you can not use a USB connection when you want to print? Also, product recommendations are off topic, so you will want to remove the last sentence to avoid this being closed.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, removed the request. USB is inconvenient because I wanted to share this with my suite, so the printer will be in a common space.

Answer (score 0):

Since that printer is not Bluetooth capable, and adapters to convert it seem difficult to find, you are limited to either connecting via USB or WiFi.

Alternately, you could setup your own personal WiFi network within your suite (using a personal router) so you connect the printer and share it. Granted, you will have to change networks when you want to print or use the university network, but it would give you the functionality you are looking for with that printer.

If that is not a workable solution, you will need to exchanging the printer for one that is Bluetooth capable.